# expect Interact call with external script prints gibberish chars append on send

Tags: bash, parameter-passing, expect, spawn

I spawn bash process from expect script to run external script file on remote server.
While it runs it ask for 1 char input with read

external script.sh:
read -n1 -p "RunFunction? [y,n]"$'\n' pulltar
case
....
ecase

Expect part is:

```
 ...
 expect -exact "RunFunction?"


          expect "\n"
          expect_user -re "(.*)\n"
          set pulltar $expect_out(1,string)
          send_user $pulltar  < this test prints single char as given y Or n
          send "$pulltar\r"   < this prints "^[[6;1Rn" and in consequence does not work
          interact -o -nobuffer -re "DONE" return
```

Example output on script run

```
RunFunction? [y,n]
n                         < send_user output
^[[6;1Rn                  < send command output, this triggers my exception
```

If I remove send command it will still work but require to provide input twice, first on "expect_user" and then again. Any suggestions ?

Comment: I've fix it. I've created var in expect :
set answer "(y|n)"
set answer [string trim $answer]
and I  pass my argument like so:
          expect -exact "RunFunction?"
          expect_user -re $answer
          set pulltar $expect_out(1,string)
          send "$pulltar\r"
          interact -o -nobuffer -re "DONE" return

Comment: Then add that as an answer and you can up vote too!

Answer (score 0):

I've fix it. I've created var in expect:

```
set answer "(y|n)" 
set answer [string trim $answer]
```

and I pass my argument like so:

```
expect -exact "RunFunction?" 
expect_user -re $answer 
set pulltar $expect_out(1,string) 
send "$pulltar\r" interact -o -nobuffer -re "DONE" return
```